# Как распарсить по тегам (ID)

Tags: json

Собственно вопрос, получаю с php аяксом масив JSON

PHP

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `work`";
   $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 
   // В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    //$arr[]=$row;
   {
        $title = $row['work'];
    $social = $row['title'];
    $text = $row['text'];
     $data = $row['data'];
    $time = $row['time'];

    $return_arr[] = array("work" => $title,
                    "title" => $social,
                    "text" => $text,
                    "data" => $data,
                    "time" => $time);


      //echo json_encode($arr);


   }
 echo json_encode($return_arr);

   mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Формат

```
 0: {…}
​​
data: "2018-06-04"
​​
text: "www.yrtyrsh"
​​
time: "14:19:21"
​​
title: "Youtube"
​​
work: "1"
```

Перехватываю Ajax

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
     $.ajax({
          url: "test.php" ,
          type:'GET',
          //data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,


  success: function(result) {


                   $('#olm').html('TITLE:' + JSON.stringify(result, ["work"] ));
                   $('#olm1').html('TITLE:' + JSON.stringify(result, ["title"] ));
                   $('#olm2').html('TITLE:' + JSON.stringify(result, ["text"] ));
                   $('#olm3').html('TITLE:' + JSON.stringify(result, ["time"] ));
   console.log(result);

}
    });
}, 15000);
```

в тег он записывает строку

```
TITLE:[{"work":"1"},{"work":"2"},{"work":"31"},{"work":"32"},{"work":"33"},{"work":"34"},{"work":"35"},{"work":"36"},{"work":"37"},{"work":"38"},{"work":"39"},{"work":"40"},{"work":"41"},{"work":"42"},{"work":"43"},{"work":"44"},{"work":"45"},{"work":"46"},{"work":"47"},{"work":"48"}]
```

Как реализовать запись в тег данных не {"work":"1"} а 1,2,3 (т.е данных из БД без кавычек, скобок и прочего)??

Comment: `result.map(function(v) { return v.work; }).join(',')`

Comment: Mike а можно в примере пожалуйста

Comment: в каком примере ? в таком ? `$('#olm').html('TITLE:' + result.map(function(v) { return v.work; }).join(','));`

Comment: Может привести в int? parseInt(JSON.stringify(result, ["work"] ))

Comment: сделайте header Content-Type:text/json, тогда result сразу будет объектом, который можно распарсить через foreach

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо)) вопросик маленький хедер  header Content-Type:text/json, имеется, можно пример  foreach?